# Angular POST request response is null (yet server returns correct string)

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, api, rest

The problem is fairly simple: I am making a request like I have always been doing up until now from my client (angular) to my .net API (3.1). The API is correctly requested and the answer is correctly sent.Yet, when it arrives on my client, the response is null. How is that?

Server side:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/XXXXXXXX")]
    [RequestSizeLimit(4_000_000_000)]
    [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.EnableCors]
    public string JsonFilterResponse([FromBody] JsonElement jsonresult)
    {
        try
        {
            var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonresult);
            if (json != null)
            {
                var savepath = ".//JsonResponses//"; Random rnd = new Random();
                var id = rnd.Next().ToString();
                var filePath = Path.Combine(savepath, id); 

                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);

                // return job complete

                Response.Body.Flush(); // http response
                Ok();
                return id; // server response --> the id of the file created
            }
            else
            {
                NotFound();
                return null;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Client side:

```
  public uploadjsonresponse(file, apiname, filename, end, appcomponent, secondapiname) {

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    });

    return this.httpClient.post(this.SERVER_URL + apiname, file, {headers: headers}).pipe(map(res => 
  {

      appcomponent.filemapper.push(filename + ";;;" + res);
      console.log(appcomponent.filemapper[appcomponent.filemapper.length-1]);
      if (end) // callback
        appcomponent.requestmapping(secondapiname, end, this);
    }));  
  }
```

The problem is that "res" comes back null client side. Yet, it is being correctly returned by the server (return id). Any ideas as to why that might be?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

When you enclose an arrow functions in curly braces, the `return` keyword should be stated explicitly. So you could append `return` to the statement that you wish to return from the `map`.

Try the following

```js
return this.httpClient.post(this.SERVER_URL + apiname, file, { headers: headers }).pipe(map(res => {
  let result = '';     // <-- change it to your desired value
  
  appcomponent.filemapper.push(filename + ";;;" + res);
  console.log(appcomponent.filemapper[appcomponent.filemapper.length - 1]);
  if (end) {       // callback
    result = appcomponent.requestmapping(secondapiname, end, this);
  }

  return result;        // <-- return result here
}));
```

---

When it comes to arrow functions

```js
const convert = (value) => /* convert and return */;
```

is the same as

```js
const convert = (value) => { return /* convert */ };
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! That's not it unfortunately. The res response returned in the client is null from the start.. though it is correctly sent back. I tried what you suggested but to no avail...

Comment: @Diveye: How do you confirm that it's correctly sent back?

Comment: I had a breakpoint on the return statement. All good now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot... Just needed to remove this in the .net API:

```
Response.Body.Flush(); // http response
```

Tada. God.